# redirect all the pages from non www to www in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I know that there is a lot info out there on redirects from non www to www domain. But my problem is that I can manage the redirect of the home page, but not the subpages.

You could see the example [here](http://ourenglishclass.eu) So when I enter the url like ourenglishclass.eu/fill-in-text-5th-6th-grade the redirect happens to the www.ourenglishclass.eu/index.php

I can see that there is probably more rewrite rules which cause it to behave this way, but I cannot find what, or how can I fix this

These are the rules which redirecting to /index.php

```
 #
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 #
 # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
 # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
 # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
 RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

I have tried these redirect rules from non-www to www:

```
  #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and (this is because i'm testing also with https)

```
  # Redirect to www
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
  RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Hopefully someone can point the way out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem appears to be due to the fact that you are placing redirect rule below your front controller rule that forwards everything to `index.php` hence making `REQUEST_URI` equal to `/index.php`.

Have your rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#
RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and solution! That works!